# How to hide sensitive information with random numbers in C# with a function

Tags: c#, random, information-hiding

I am looking for a function that takes in a line of customer info like this sample:

```
125478744|John|Smith|1234567890123456|50.00|Dinner
```

Then I will then split that info and place it in a string array with this function:

```
private static string[] ScrubData(string text)
    {
        //here is where the string is broken apart
        String[] customerInfo = text.Split('|');
        return customerInfo;
    }
```

Then I need another function that will do the following:

Replace the first column of numbers which would be social security numbers with nine random numbers between 1 and 9.

Then the third column which is the customer's last name, I need to generate random letters for each character of the last name and replace them.

In column 4, which would be account numbers, I need to replace all the numbers except for the last 4 with 'X'.

In column 5, which is the amount, I need check to see if the amount is greater than 100.  If it is, I need to create a new column at the end of the line of info that says yes or no if the amount is greater than 100.

I will be using the following random number generators and random character generator functions:

```
public static char GetRandomLetter()
{
    string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    Random rand = new Random();
    int num = rand.Next(0, chars.Length -1);
    return chars[num];
}

public static int GetRandomNumber()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int ranNum = rnd.Next(10);//creates random number between 0 and 9
    return ranNum;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: SO isn't a code-writing service, have you tried anything? This looks like homework since it really isn't a valid form of encryption or hiding sensitive data...

Comment: Sounds like you know what you want in regards to the steps that you have laid out.. `No Start coding your own solution`

Comment: Well, you can explain it, you know how to get it separated, you know which columns are where, you have randomness generated...now go do it. BTW, it sounds like you only really care about the *real* value of a few columns so don't "replace" anything, just generate random stuff to begin with.

Comment: You should make an attempt at each step in this question... You'll probably figure it out on your own (more valuable than someone *telling* you how to do it). If not, come back with *the specific problem* you are having and someone will absolutely help you out.

Comment: you know the column which needs to be replace and you have the autorandom generated values just try pass the random value to column you want like `customerInfo[0] = GetRandomNumber().ToString();`

Comment: Thanks Ron, I realize this is not a code writing service..  I have indeed been trying..  Perhaps I should not have tagged it with privacy, encryption,  or information-hiding, I was just hoping to get more replies..  This is my first time here and I did not expect to get so many comments so fast..  This is a tiny piece of my whole task assigned to me, its the only one which has me scratching my head...

Answer (score 0):

Your two random functions each create a new instance of `Random`.  Don't do that.  You only need one instance of `Random` for your whole program.

Your `GetRandomNumber()` method returns an integer, not a character.  Better to write something more like your other method, for letters:

```
Random rand = new Random();  // Only one instance of Random.

public static char GetRandomDigit()
{
    string digits = "0123456789";
    int pick = rand.Next(0, digits.Length - 1);
    return digits[pick];
}
```

As others have said, you can already separate the data into parts.  Just write small sub-programs to deal with each part individually.  That breaks a large problem into smaller problems that are easier to solve.

Comment: Thank you rossom, much appreciated...   I used the Thread.Sleep() method to avoid getting the same numbers and letters..